# Create new column datetime with add minutes (Pandas, Python)

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I newest in Pandas,
Please help with the next issue:

1. I get the datatable from MS SQL DataBase, like:

```
(datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 1, 0, 0), 'ECS446_FSL_969_D01_F41', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60', '60'), **...**)
```

2. Input Data in Pandas DataFrame and did next step:

Columns '0'...'59' is a minutes in hour('DataTime') with values of 'TagName'.
Did next transformations:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(result2, columns=['DataTime', 'TagName', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59'])
df1 = df1.pivot(index='TagName', columns= 'DataTime', values=['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9','10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19','20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49','50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59'])
df1 = df1.T
df1 = df1.sort_values('DataTime')
```

And have to result:

[image: picture1]

3. The problem is to add minutes to the DateTime column,
   I want to get the following result:

[image: picture2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#sample data
a = [pd.to_datetime('2020-12-01'), 'code1'] + [60] * 60
b =  [pd.to_datetime('2020-12-01 10:00:00'), 'code2'] + [5] * 60
result2  = [a, b]

cols = ['DataTime', 'TagName', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]

df = pd.DataFrame(result2, columns=cols)
```

First unpivot by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), add minutes to datetimes by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and last pivoting:

```
df1 = df.melt(['DataTime', 'TagName'], var_name='minutes', value_name='data')

df1['DataTime'] += pd.to_timedelta(df1['minutes'], unit='Min')
print (df1)

df2 = df1.pivot('DataTime','TagName','data')
print (df2)
```

Comment: @YaEG - Can you be more specific?

Comment: I change the text to picture, please see it.

Comment: @YaEG - Unfortunately I cannot see there problem.

Comment: Ok, I try to explain: from MS SQL DB get the next table with columns: 1) DateTime, TagName, and column: values in minutes of the hour a DateTime (from 0 to 59 minutes). 2) I want to transform the table in the next view: DateTime (with add-in hour minutes from 0 to 59) | TAG1, TAG2,.....TAG N (values) (see picture2)

Comment: @YaEG - Is possible see `print(type(result2))` ?

Comment: @YaEG - and if DataFrame what is `print (result2.head(3).to_dict())` ?

Comment: print(type(result2))           -->          <class 'list'>

Comment: print (result2.head(3).to_dict())    -->   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pythonProject\GetHistTags\sql.py", line 226, in <module>
    print(result2.head(3).to_dict())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'head'

Comment: @YaEG - Super! Thank you for patience.